# inheritance ria services form "DomainService" and "LinqToEntitiesDomainService<>"

Tags: .net, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

i have piece of code like this :

```
namespace SilverlightApplication1.Web
{
    [DataContractAttribute(IsReference = true)]
    public class CustomEntity 
    {
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public Person MyPerson { get; set; }

        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public Address MyAddress { get; set; }

        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public List<Order> MyOreders { get; set; }

    }
}
```

that is like wrapper over some ef entities. the problem is that when i write a service to expose this class for silverlight client like this :

```
[EnableClientAccess]
public class DomainService2 : DomainServices
{
    [Invoke]
    public IEnumerable<CustomEntity> GetAllCustomEntities()
    {
        var ent = new AllDataBaseEntities();
        return ent.Persons.Select(x => new CustomEntity()
        {
            MyPerson= x,
            MyAddrees= x.Address,
            MyOrders=x.Orders.ToList()

        });
    }
```

if I inherite from "DomainService" and write my code like above , all of my CustomEntity's Properties exposed on client side. otherwise if i write my service like this :

```
[EnableClientAccess()] 
public class DomainService1 : LinqToEntitiesDomainService<AllDataBaseEntities> {

        public IEnumerable<CustomEntity> GetAllCustomEntities()
        {
            return ObjectContext.Persons.Select(x => new CustomEntity()
            {
                MyPerson= x,
                MyAddrees= x.Address,
                MyOrders=x.Orders.ToList()

            });
        }

}
```

neither of my CustomEntity's properties available on client side.

My question is that how can I use both of this methods in my programs.note that if i use "LinqToEntitiesDomainService<> " in my program then the other one does not work correctly.

And note that i do not want and i can not use [Association] attribute because for what i want to use this method, all of the custom entities properties does not have relation with each other, and i want to call one service instead of multiple services to load my data on client side

thank you for attention

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your implementation but normally in my Silverlight projects I follow this technique: [Sharing Entities in Silverlight](http://10rem.net/blog/2009/07/13/sharing-entities-between-wcf-and-silverlight)

Comment: thanks for your reply. but this is not my problem. and in link that you provided, only primary data types discussed.